# Is it possible to use the console on a Juniper EX for outbound connections?

Tags: juniper

I want to connect two EX switches by console cable and want to use this connection to open a console session from one EX to the other. I found no "offical" way to do this but maybe someone else has succeeded?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No - the console ports on the EX cannot be used like this.

If you have both EXs in a virtual chassis though, you can console into one and then execute

```
request session member 1
```

to jump into the console of the second device.